# Scrappy empty csv/json

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am start to use scrapy. I write my code following the tutorial from documentation. When i run to output a json or a csv, the file outputed is empty. When I test my selector in the shell i got the data. I will post my code:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "adororomance"
    start_urls = [
            'http://www.adororomances.com.br/arromances.php?cod=01',
            ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for livro in response.xpath('//*[@id="page_livro_coluna"]'):
            yield {
                    'titulo':
                    livro.xpath(
                        '//*[@id="page_livro_coluna"]/div[1]/h1/text()').extract_first(),
                    'autor(a)':
                    livro.xpath(
                        '//*[@id="page_livro_coluna"]/div[2]/span/a/span/h2/text()').extract_first(),
                    'titulo original':
                    livro.xpath(
                        '//*[@id="page_livro_coluna"]/div[3]/text()').extract_first(),
                    'coleção':
                    livro.xpath(
                        '//*[@id="page_livro_coluna"]/div[4]/h3/a/text()').extract_first(),
                    'publicação':
                    livro.xpath(
                        '//*[@id="page_livro_coluna"]/div[4]/div[1]/span[1]/text()').extract_first(),
                    'ano':
                    livro.xpath(
                        '//*[@id="page_livro_coluna"]/div[4]/div[1]/span[2]/text()').extract_first(),
                    'série':
                    livro.xpath(
                        '//*[@id="page_livro_coluna"]/div[4]/div[2]/a/span/text()').extract_first(),
                    'descrição':
                    livro.css(
                        '//*[@id="description"]/text()')
                      .extract_first(),
            }
```

By testing, I discover that `'descrição'` is broking the code, if i remove the json renders. When, in the shell, i put the selector, I got:

```
['\r\n\t\t\t\t \r\n\t\t\t\t Ser sequestrada por um sheik árabe nem passou pela cabeça de Diane, ao visitar o deserto do Saara. Porém, foi o que aconteceu. Khasim ben Haran era um homem poderoso e arrogante, cujo único objetivo, ao fazer dela sua prisioneira, era vingar a morte da mãe. No entanto, esse mesmo homem que a aterrorizava, com ameaças cruéis, também a fascinava. E a figura altiva e exótica não saía da mente de Diane nem por um instante... \r\n                \r\n              ']
```

One more question: this line breaks `\r\n\t` will render in my json? if yes, how I can get rid of them?

thanks

Comment: Did you check if the `response.css` is getting data? Also how did you run the crawl command?

Comment: Please, see my edited response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `livro.css('//*[@id="description"]/text()').extract_first(),` should be `livro.xpath('//*[@id="description"]/text()').extract_first(),`. Using xpath inside a css selector will raise an exception that will kill the scraping process and that's probably the reason why you don't get anything on your output.

Second, line breaks like `\r\n\t` will be keeped on your json file and they will be rendered  or not based on the software you use  to inspect the json file. If you want to remove then you can use the `strip()` function:

```
livro.xpath('//*[@id="description"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
```

Please, notice that if the xpath doesn't find any information it will return `None` and `strip()` will fail, in that case you will have to add an extra check to be sure the value is not `None`

Comment: Thank you. Change to `livro.xpath` works. To deal with the line breaks I did: `livro.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="description"]/text())').extract_first()`